# PHP Implode wrap in tags

Tags: php, html, implode

Been trying to google an answer but cant seem to find anything, I have the following...

```
<?php
    $values =   array_map('trim', get_post_custom_values($key));
    $value  =   implode($values,', ');
    echo "<div class='top-meta-vals'>".apply_filters(" $value\n", $value)."</div>";
?>
```

I want to wrap each and every `$value` in a span tag but im unsure how...

I tried,

```
<?php
$value = "<span>".implode($values,', ')."</span>";
?>
```

with no luck, can anybody give me an idea of where im going wrong?

Comment: `$value = '<span>'.implode('<span>, </span>', $values).'</span>';`

Comment: Comment above is wrong. Should be '</span>, <span>' in implode

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In this way you are wrapping the entire set in one span, you have to add the closing/opening tag to the implode:

```
$value = "<span>".implode('</span>,<span>', $values)."</span>";
```

Comment: Just to mention : with empty `$tags` array it would become `<span></span>` string.

Comment: Flip the parameters to implode and then it's correct, should be: implode('</span>,<span>', $values)

Comment: To resolve the empty $values issue resulting in $value as an empty span element you can `echo trim( $value, '<span></span>');`

Comment: Got same problem today. Added additional `empty()` clause: `empty($values) ? "" : "<span>".implode('</span>,<span>', $values)."</span>";`

Answer (score 21):

You can use `array_map` function, smth like this:

```
$filter = function($tag){ return '<span>' . $tag . '</span>'; };
$spannedTags = array_map($filter, $tags);
```

End then just implode with `,`.

Answer (score 8):

Basically, this just implodes your values, using the 'glue' of span closed/open, and wraps it so the first and last items have their beginning/ending spans tags:

```
$value = "<span>" . implode("</span><span>", $values) . "</span>";
```