# PHP: Trim to get rid of empty span

Tags: php, trim

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872670/php-implode-wrap-in-tags#comment32611432_9872698) comment.

```
$values = array("foo","bar");
```

`var_dump($value)` results in:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'foo' (length=3)
  1 => string 'bar' (length=3)
```

Implode:

```
$value = "<span>".implode('</span>,<span>', $values)."</span>";
```

Now `var_dump($value)` results in:

```
string '<span>foo</span>,<span>bar</span>' (length=33)
```

Trim:

```
$value = trim($value,"<span></span>");
```

Now `var_dump($value)` results in:

```
string 'foo</span>,<span>bar' (length=20)
```

But it should still result in:

```
string '<span>foo</span>,<span>bar</span>' (length=33)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `str_replace()` be better for this?

Comment: I don't think [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) does [what you think it does](http://php.net/str-replace)

Comment: Why would you trim it once you had the results you were seeking?

Comment: I don't know, whould it? `$value = str_replace("<span></span>","",$value);`?

Comment: Trim seems like it is doing exactly what it should in your example above.

Comment: `$value = trim($value,"</span>");` does the same thing. Second parameter to trim are characters you want to remove.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: To make sure not to get `<span></span>` if `$values` is empty.

Comment: If i understand you, Seems like you are trying to use an array. First check whether the array has empty keys and clear the array. You can follow this link http://gotofritz.net/blog/howto/removing-empty-array-elements-php/ or similar to find how to clear the empty elements in the array. Then use the array. You will never get empty <span></span> pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function works at the character level, not the text or HTML tag level.

When you do `trim($value, "<span></span>")` you're asking PHP to remove all leading and trailing characters that appear in the text `<span></span>`.  This has the same result as doing `trim($value, "/<>anps")`

You should probably use `str_replace`instead.

Alternately, use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove the blank entries in the array *before* you `implode` them.
For example:

```
$str = implode("</span>,<span>", array_filter($values, 'strlen'));
```

Comment: @santa - Yep.  Dead wrong.  They probably meant `str_replace` and not `trim`.